# insert command inserts several rows in table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm using this code to insert in database , but every time it inserts more than one row ,what is the problem ?

```
    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim dob As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form(TextBox6.UniqueID))

    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqlexpress").ConnectionString

    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)

        Dim com As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO main (GroupID, Name, Description, ModeUD, StartNum, StartDate, Rate) VALUES (" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "'," & Me.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value & "," & TextBox4.Text & ",'" & dob & "'," & TextBox5.Text & ")", con)

        con.Open()
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()





    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: User doubleclicks, triggers that are called, some funky multiple event handler registration with addhandler, PerformClick() in a LostFocus or Validating, etc...

Comment: Don not string concat. Use parameters. Sqlinjection heaven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked and hole the button click was executed twice , I have changed the code to this one and it has been solved , but I dont know why the click event is executed twice :

```
 Dim i As Boolean = True


  Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim dob As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form(TextBox6.UniqueID))

    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sqlexpress").ConnectionString





    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conString)
        con.Open()
        Using com As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO main (GroupID, Name, Description, ModeUD, StartNum, StartDate, Rate) VALUES (" & TextBox1.Text & ",'" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "'," & Me.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value & "," & TextBox4.Text & ",'" & dob & "'," & TextBox5.Text & ")", con)
            If i = True Then





                com.ExecuteScalar()
                i = False
            End If

        End Using
        con.Close()

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to put a break point in that code and investigate the call stack.  That will tell you where it's coming from.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked to see if your block of code is being called more than once?  One quick way is to put a alert box inside so you can count the times it runs.

Answer (score 2):

Well... there are lots of problems.  The first of which is the potential for SQL Injection, you should be using named parameters.  Another is that the line about `Dim com As New...` should also be in a `Using` clause.

However, nothing in that bit of code suggests that it is inserting more than 1 record.  I suggest you put a break point on the `ExecuteNonQuery` line and see what's going on.